# What does it mean "Hawking radiation is in a pure state"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, hilbert-space, hawking-radiation, unitarity

I'm trying to understand black hole paradox but I'm not sure if I understand what does it mean "Hawking radiation is in a pure state". Does it mean if Hawking radiation is in a mixed state then information is lost?

UPDATE: My understanding is that a system is said to be in a pure state if we have complete knowledge about that system, meaning we know exactly which state it's in.
On other other hand, a system is in a mixed state if we only have partial (or no) knowledge of the system. In terms of a probability density, ρ say, this means that more than one of its eigenvalues must be non-zero.

That is all relatively clear to me. But when they introduce "Hawking radiation" and start questioning whether "Hawking radiation" is a pure or mixed state I'm confused. What does this mean?

Comment: To me *"Hawking radiation is in a pure state"* seems pretty clear - it is *in a pure state*, not in a mixed one (nothing ever really is in a mixed state, mixed states only represent that an observer is missing (or not caring about) some knowledge). I'm not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it is often stressed that Hawking radiation is in a pure state, is that this is in apparent contradiction to the fact that Hawking radiation is also said to be thermal. The apparent contradiction is solved when one realizes that in a general curved spacetime there is no unique definition of the vacuum state and therefore the whole Hilbert space.

Consequently, an observer at infinity will see a thermal bath of particles (i.e. in a **mixed** state) coming from the horizon, even though the quantum fields are in the **local** vacuum state near the horizon.